# Path construction or drawing operators aren't allowed inside a text object

Tags: java, itext

When I'm trying to draw a line using **itextpdf-5.5.4.jar** with the below code(`PdfContentByteobject`)

`contentByte.moveTo(55, 755)`. this is throwing the exception

```
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Path construction or drawing operators aren't allowed inside a text object.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.moveTo(PdfContentByte.java:776)
    at DemoS.TextPostion.createPdfHeader(TextPostion.java:652)
    at DemoS.TextPostion.fillCelldata(TextPostion.java:352)
    at DemoS.TextPostion.createPDF(TextPostion.java:175)
    at DemoS.TextPostion.main(TextPostion.java:128)
```

but the same code working fine with **itextpdf-5.0.6.jar**  Any suggestion?
How can I do the same  job using itextpdf-5.0.6.jar  .

Comment: I think you need to show some more code..

Comment: The message "Path construction or drawing operators aren't allowed inside a text object." Is correct, if you are in a text object, you have to do *endText* before drawing the line. You may continue drawing text thereafter by doing *beginText* first.

Comment: yes. You are right but the same code is working good with itextpdf-5.0.6.jar ?

Comment: *but the same code is working good with itextpdf-5.0.6.jar* - it may be *working* with iText 5.0.6 but it is not *working **good*** as it creates broken PDF. Most PDF viewer will show that broken PDF anyways but it is broken nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **mkl** mentioned in comment that before drawing the line we have first end this and after drawing begin the text object. like-

```
...
contentByte.endText();
contentByte.moveTo(50, 637);
contentByte.lineTo(5400, 637);
contentByte.stroke();
contentByte.beginText();
```

but be careful if you are using stroke and call `beginText()` after `contentByte.stroke()`.

This resolve my problem.

Comment: Your code worked in old versions, but it created PDFs that were in violation with the ISO standard.